# Find neighbors given a specific coordinate in a 2D array

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a problem using python and this is my first time to write python so I hope you could help me out. I have a 2D array its values is `-1,0,1` what I want to do is take the co-ordinates of a specific element and get the co-ordinates of all the adjacent elements

```
Matrix = [[ 1,-1, 0],
          [ 1, 0, 0],
          [-1,-1, 1]]
```

for example if I have `(0,0)` so the function could return `(0,1)`,`(1,0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to work from the *coordinates*, a simple way I can think of is to define a grid graph using [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) and to look for the [`neighbours`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.neighbors.html):

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,-1,0],
              [1,0,0],
              [-1,-1,1]])

G = nx.grid_2d_graph(*a.shape)
list(G.neighbors((0,0)))
# [(1, 0), (0, 1)]
```

Or for the "coordinates" of the middle value for instance:

```
list(G.neighbors((1,1)))
# [(0, 1), (2, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2)]
```

If you want to use them to index the array:

```
ix = list(G.neighbors((0,0)))
a[tuple(ix)]
# array([ 1, -1])
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the best solution but it can help if you don't want to import any lib:

```
def get_neighbors(matrix, x, y):
    positions = []
    positions.append(get_neighbor(matrix, x, y-1))
    positions.append(get_neighbor(matrix, x, y+1))
    positions.append(get_neighbor(matrix, x-1, y))
    positions.append(get_neighbor(matrix, x+1, y))

    return list(filter(None, positions))

def get_neighbor(matrix, x, y):
    if (x >= 0 and x < len(matrix[0])) and (y >= 0 and y < len(matrix[1])):
        return (x, y)
```

get_neighbors(your_matrix, x_position, y_position)